# Climber rankings at Tour de France - must the winner finish the tour?

Tags: rules, ranking, cycling, tour-de-france

What if a few (2/3) stages to the end of the Tour de France a cyclist retires when he had a number of points that would make it mathematically unreachable by other cyclists in the climber ranking?

> Does he win the climber rankings or is it necessary to arrive to Champ Elysee?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quote from [2016 Tour de France rules](http://netstorage.lequipe.fr/ASO/cyclisme/le-tour/2016/reglement/TDF16_Reglement_BD.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> ARTICLE 24|RANKINGS
>   ...
>   c) General best climber ranking
>   The general best climber ranking is established by adding together the points obtained on all passes and hills, according to the following tables:
>   ...
>   Riders **must finish** the Tour de France in order to appear in the best climber ranking.

A similar rule is mentioned for [points classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_classification_in_the_Tour_de_France), too.

Answer (score 3):

When rules didn't specify that the rider had to finish the Tour, the Climber Jersey was awarded to [Félicien Vervaecke (1937)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1937_Tour_de_France) even when he didn't finish the tour.

> After the last mountain in the fifteenth stage, the [mountain] classification was won by Félicien Vervaecke. Vervaecke did not finish the Tour, but in 1937 that was not needed to win the mountains classification.
>   <sub>Source: Wikipedia</sub>