# Climber or Points rankings leader not finishing Tour de France

Tags: trivia, history, ranking, cycling, tour-de-france

Has it ever happened that the cyclist who has collected the most points in one of these two rankings (climber or points) has not finished the Tour, leaving the victory of the "jersey" to another rider?

I remember that [winner is the cyclist that has most points amongst all who arrive at the Champs Elysees](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/climber-rankings-at-tour-de-france-must-the-winner-finish-the-tour).

Obviously for picking up a number of points higher than those obtained by the cyclist who finally won the respective ranking any cyclist must have finished a large number of stages (the case that comes to mind is that of the sprinter who collects many points in the early stages of level standard and then retired during "the third" week when there are more mountain stages, it is unlikely that this can happen for the ranking of the climbers for the same reason)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find any occurrence of a climber abandoning at a final stage with a higher number of climbing points leaving the Red-Dotted jersey to the runner-up.

However, I found some cases:

- In 2009, [Franco Pellizotti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franco_Pellizotti) finished the Tour as leader of the Red-Dotted jersey with 210 points, however after suspicious blood values, his results were cancelled and the jersey re-attributed to Egoi Martinez who finished second with 135.
- In 2008, [Bernhad Kohl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Kohl) finished with 120 points but was disqualified so Carlos Sastre won the jersey with 80 points.

Answer (score 0):

At the 2017 Tour de France Marcel Kittel had 373 points in the green jersey competition after [stage 16](https://www.cyclingnews.com/races/tour-de-france-2017/stage-16/results/). He abandoned the next day. Michael Matthews eventually won the green jersey with [370 points](https://www.cyclingnews.com/races/tour-de-france-2017/stage-21/results/), less than what Kittel had.